# STM32H747 Register implemented ADC with DMA

Tags: stm32, dma, adc, stm32h7

I'm using the H747 on a Arduino Portenta H7. I'm trying to implement the ADC and DMA together.
The ADC should run in continous mode and scan over the 2 channels.

```
void ADC_Init (void){
/******Enable ADC Voltage regulator******/
ADC1->CR&= ~(1<<29); //DEEPPWD set to zero to set adc not deep power down
ADC1->CR|= ADC_CR_ADVREGEN; //Turn on voltage regulator ADC |=(1<<28)
digitalWrite(LEDR,LOW);
//while (!(ADC1->ISR & (1<<12)));  //LDORDY: ADC LDO output voltage ready bit

/******Enable ADC CLOCK******/
RCC->AHB1ENR|=(1<<5);//ADC peripheral clock enable
//RCC->D3CCIPR&= ~(7<<16)// ADCSEL[1:0]: SAR ADC kernel clock source selection default
ADC1->CR|=(3<<8);


/******Set the prescalar******/
ADC12_COMMON->CCR &= ~(15<<18);// PRESC[3:0]: ADC prescaler 0000: input ADC clock not divided
ADC12_COMMON->CCR &= ~(3<<16);// CKMODE[3:0]: ADC clock mode


/******Set Scan Mode Data Management and resolution******/
ADC1->CFGR|=(6<<2);  //RES[2:0]: Data resolution 110=12bits
ADC1->CFGR|=(3<<0);  //DMNGT[1:0]: Data Management configuration 11: DMA Circular Mode selected

//ADC regular sequence register 1
ADC1->SQR1|=(1<<0);  // L[3:0]: Regular channel sequence length 1=2 conversions
ADC1->SQR1&= ~(0<<6);// SQ1[4:0]: 1st conversion in regular sequence channel number =0
ADC1->SQR1&= ~(1<<12);// SQ1[4:0]: 2st conversion in regular sequence channel number =1


/******Set the Continuous Conversion, ******/
ADC1->CFGR|=(1<<13);  //CONT: Single / continuous conversion mode for regular conversions

/******Set the Sampling Time for the channels in ADC_SMPRx******/
ADC1->SMPR1&= ~(7<<0);//SMP0[2:0]: Channel 0 sampling time selection 000: 1.5 ADC clock cycles
ADC1->SMPR1&= ~(7<<3);//SMP1[2:0]: Channel 1 sampling time selection 000: 1.5 ADC clock cycles
ADC1->PCSEL|= (1<<0);//PCSEL[19:0] :Channel 0 (VINP[i]) pre selection 
ADC1->PCSEL|= (1<<1);//PCSEL[19:0] :Channel 1 (VINP[i]) pre selection 

/******Set singleEnded Input******/
ADC1->DIFSEL&= ~(1<<0); //DIFSEL[19:0]: Differential mode for channels 19 to 0
ADC1->DIFSEL&= ~(1<<1); //DIFSEL[19:0]: Differential mode for channels 19 to 0


/******Enable ADC******/
ADC1->ISR|=(1<<0); // Reset ADC ready flag
ADC1->CR|= ADC_CR_ADEN; //Enable ADC
while (!(ADC1->ISR & (1<<0)));  //Wait for ready flag
ADC1->ISR|=(1<<0);}
```

The DMA should catch the output from the adc and move them into memory

```
void DMA_Init (void){
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1<<0);
    DMA1_Stream0->CR &= ~(0x1 << 0);
    while (DMA1_Stream0->CR & 0x1);
 
    DMA1_Stream0->CR |= (0x3 << 16);
    DMA1_Stream0->CR &= ~(3<<6);  //Bits 7:6 DIR[1:0]: data transfer direction
    DMA1_Stream0->CR |= (1<<8);  //CIRC: circular mode
    DMA1_Stream0->CR |= (1<<10);  // MINC = 1;
    DMA1_Stream0->CR |= (1<<11)|(1<<13);  // MSIZE[1:0]: memory data size PSIZE[1:0]: peripheral data size
    DMA1_Stream0->CR &= ~(7<<25);  // Channel 0 selected
    DMAMUX1_Channel0->CCR |=(9<<0);
    DMA1_Stream0->CR |= (0x1 << 4);
    DMA1_Stream0->CR |= (0x1 << 3);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream0_IRQn);
}
void DMA_Config (uint32_t srcAdd, uint32_t destAdd, uint16_t s){
     
  DMA1_Stream0->NDTR = s;   // Set the size of the transfer
  DMA1_Stream0->PAR = srcAdd;  // Source address is peripheral address
  DMA1_Stream0->M0AR = destAdd;  // Destination Address is memory address
  // Enable the DMA Stream
  DMA1_Stream0->CR |= (1<<0);  // EN =1
}
```

When running the code it gets stuck in ADCStart() at ADC1->CR|= ADC_CR_ADON;

```
void setup() {
  SystemClock_Config();
  ADC_Init();
  DMA_Init();
  DMA_Config ((uint32_t ) &ADC1->DR, (uint32_t) RxData, 3);
  ADC_start();
  digitalWrite(LEDB,LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600); //for debuging
}
void ADC_start (void){
    while ((ADC1->CR & (1<<1)));
    ADC1->CR|= ADC_CR_ADON;
}
```

Is my procedure wrong?

- configure adc
- configure dma
- start adc

I'm still new to stm32 so I used https://controllerstech.com/dma-with-adc-using-registers-in-stm32/ as guidance and the reference manual of stm32h7

Comment: here is much more to configure for example DMAMUX. Do not use magic numbers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure wether you still need an answer to your question.
Here is what I did with your code :
(I don't have any library installed for the portenta so I declared every registers above, I am french so some of my comments are written in frenglish I apologize for that...).

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <string.h>
#define HWREG(x)    (*((volatile uint32_t *)(x)))
//REGISTRE DEF---------------------------------------------------
//REG DMA1---------------------------------------------
volatile uint32_t* const DMA_LISR = (uint32_t *) 0x40020000;
volatile uint32_t* const DMA_HISR = (uint32_t *) 0x40020004;
volatile uint32_t* const DMA_LIFCR = (uint32_t *) 0x40020008;
volatile uint32_t* const DMA_HIFCR = (uint32_t *) 0x4002000C;
volatile uint32_t* const DMA_S1CR = (uint32_t *) 0x40020028;
volatile uint32_t* const DMA_S1NDTR = (uint32_t *) 0x4002002C;
volatile uint32_t* const DMA_S1PAR = (uint32_t *) 0x40020030;
volatile uint32_t* const DMA_S1M0AR = (uint32_t *) 0x40020034;//Mem 1 no use since no double buffer in mem2mem
volatile uint32_t* const DMA_S1FCR = (uint32_t *) 0x4002003C;
uint32_t S1CR = *DMA_S1CR;
uint32_t S1FCR = *DMA_S1FCR;
uint32_t S1PAR = *DMA_S1PAR;
uint32_t S1M0AR = *DMA_S1M0AR;
uint32_t S1NDTR = *DMA_S1NDTR;
//REG DMAMUX-------------------------------------------
volatile uint32_t* const DMAMUX1_C1CR = (uint32_t *) 0x40020804;//adresse dmamux1_chan1
uint32_t C1CR = *DMAMUX1_C1CR;
//REG ADC----------------------------------------------
//--------------------ADC REGISTRES-------------------//
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_ISR = (uint32_t *) 0x40022000;//Interupt and status register
uint32_t ISR = *ADC_ISR;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_IER = (uint32_t *) 0x40022004;//Interupt enable register
uint32_t IER = *ADC_IER;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_CR = (uint32_t *) 0x40022008;//Control register
uint32_t CR = *ADC_CR;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_CFGR = (uint32_t *) 0x4002200C;//COnfiguration register
uint32_t CFGR = *ADC_CFGR;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_CFGR2 = (uint32_t *) 0x40022010;//2eme conf regrister
uint32_t CFGR2 = *ADC_CFGR2;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_SMPR1 = (uint32_t *) 0x40022014; //Sample time reg (directement lié au temps de calc de l'ADC)
uint32_t SMPR1 = *ADC_SMPR1;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_PCSEL = (uint32_t*) 0x4002201C;//channel preselection register on choisis un chan pour la conv
uint32_t PCSEL = *ADC_PCSEL;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_DR = (uint32_t *) 0x40022040;//Registre où l'on stocke le resultat des conv
uint32_t DR = *ADC_DR;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_DIFSEL = (uint32_t *) 0x400220C0;
uint32_t DIFSEL = *ADC_DIFSEL;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC_SQR1 = (uint32_t *) 0x40022030;
uint32_t SQR1 = *ADC_SQR1;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC1_CSR = (uint32_t *) 0x40022300;//ADC1 common status register
uint32_t CSR = *ADC1_CSR;
volatile uint32_t* const ADC1_CCR = (uint32_t *)0x40022308; //ADC1 Common Control Register
uint32_t CCR = *ADC1_CCR;
//REG RCC-----------------------------------------------
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_APB4ENR = (uint32_t *) 0x580244F4;//to enable sysconf
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_AHB4ENR =(uint32_t *) 0x580244E0;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_AHB1ENR =(uint32_t *) 0x580244D8;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_CR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024400;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_CFGR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024410;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_D1CFGR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024418;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_D2CFGR = (uint32_t *) 0x5802441C;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_D3CFGR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024420;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_PLLCKSELR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024428;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_PLLCFGR = (uint32_t *) 0x5802442C;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_PLL1DIVR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024430;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_PLL1FRACR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024434;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_PLL2DIVR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024438;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_PLL2FRACR = (uint32_t *) 0x5802443C;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_PLL3DIVR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024440;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_PLL3FRACR = (uint32_t *) 0x58024444;
volatile uint32_t* const RCC_CIER = (uint32_t *) 0x58024460;
//setup---------------------------------------------
int dataFromRegister = 0;
void SystemClock_Config();
void ADC_start();
void ADC_Init();
void DMA_Init();
void DMA_Config();
void setup(){
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600); //for debuging
  digitalWrite(LEDR, LOW);
  //Serial.println("Début");
  SystemClock_Config();
  //Serial.println("ClockConf");
  ADC_Init();
  //Serial.println("Init_ADC");
  DMA_Init();
  //Serial.println("Init_DMA");
  DMA_Config ();
  //Serial.println("Config_DMA");
  ADC_start();
  //Serial.println("ADC_Start");
  digitalWrite(LEDB,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //
}
void ADC_start (void){
  CR&=~(1 << 30);
  *ADC_CR=CR; 
  //On a deja ADCALDIF en single ended inputs mode par nos initialisations précédentes
  CR=(1<<16);//ADCALLIN calibration linéaire ET offset
  *ADC_CR=CR;
  //CR=0x90010001;
  *ADC_CR|=(1<<31);//Lancer une calibration ADCAL=1
  //dataFromRegister=*ADC_CR;
  while(*ADC_CR & 0x80000000!=0x00000000){
    digitalWrite(LEDR,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LEDR,LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }digitalWrite(LEDR,HIGH);
  //On attends que la calibration soit complète par un reset de ADCAL
  //Processus de calibration terminé (Serial.println(/*dataFromRegister,BIN*/"calibration");)
  /******Enable ADC******/
  *ADC_ISR |= (1 << 0); // Reset ADC ready flag
  *ADC_CR |=(1 << 0); //Enable ADC
  while (!(*ADC_ISR & (1 << 0))); //Wait for ready flag
  *ADC_ISR |= (1 << 0);
  *ADC_CR |= (3 << 8);//11 boost if  ADC Clock entre 25 et 50MHz
  //ADSTART
  CR|=(1<<2);
  *ADC_CR=CR;
}

void ADC_Init (void) {
  /******Enable ADC Voltage regulator******/
  CR=0x00000000;//Fin du deep power down
  *ADC_CR=CR;
  CR=0x10000000;//ADC voltage regulator Enable
  *ADC_CR=CR;
  while(*ADC_CR & 0x00001000!=0x00001000){}//check volatage enable (peut etre remplacé par un :
  //delayMicroseconds(5); mais c'est moins safe)
  //Petit interlude Differentiel ou single ended (a faire avant ADEN)---------
  DIFSEL=0x00000000;
  *ADC_DIFSEL=DIFSEL;
  //digitalWrite(LEDR, LOW);
  //while (!(ADC1_ISR & (1<<12)));  //LDORDY: ADC LDO output voltage ready bit
  /******Calibrate ADC*********/
  /******Enable ADC CLOCK******/
  
  *RCC_AHB1ENR |= (1 << 5); //ADC peripheral clock enable
  //RCC_D3CCIPR&= ~(7<<16)// ADCSEL[1:0]: SAR ADC kernel clock source selection default
  digitalWrite(LEDB,LOW);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(LEDB,HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(LEDB,LOW);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(LEDB,HIGH);
  /******Set the prescalar******/
  CCR=0x000F0000;
  *ADC1_CCR=CCR;


  /******Set Scan Mode Data Management and resolution******/
  CFGR |= (6 << 2); //RES[2:0]: Data resolution 110=12bits
  CFGR |= (3 << 0); //DMNGT[1:0]: Data Management configuration 11: DMA circular mode
  *ADC_CFGR=CFGR;
  
  //ADC regular sequence register 1
  SQR1=0x00000000;//1st conv correspond au chan 0 (00000) et on réalise une conv par sequence de 1 conv(0000)
  *ADC_SQR1=SQR1;

  /******Set the Continuous Conversion, ******/
  CFGR |= (1 << 13); //CONT: Single / continuous conversion mode for regular conversions
  *ADC_CFGR=CFGR;
  
  /******Set the Sampling Time for the channels in ADC_SMPRx******/
  SMPR1 &= ~(7 << 0); //SMP0[2:0]: Channel 0 sampling time selection 000: 1.5 ADC clock cycles
  *ADC_SMPR1=SMPR1;
  PCSEL |= (1 << 0); //PCSEL[19:0] :Channel 0 (VINP[i]) pre selection
  *ADC_PCSEL=PCSEL;
  
  /******Set singleEnded Input******/
  DIFSEL &= ~(1 << 0); //DIFSEL[19:0]: single ended mode for channel 0
  *ADC_DIFSEL=DIFSEL;
  
  
}

void DMA_Init (void){
    *RCC_AHB1ENR |= (1<<0);
    *DMA_S1CR &= ~(1 << 0);
    while (*DMA_S1CR & 0x1);
 
    *DMA_S1CR |= (3 << 16);
    *DMA_S1CR &= ~(3<<6);  //Bits 7:6 DIR[1:0]: data transfer direction
    *DMA_S1CR |= (1<<8);  //CIRC: circular mode
    *DMA_S1CR |= (1<<10);  // MINC = 1;
    *DMA_S1CR |= (1<<11)|(1<<13);  // MSIZE[1:0]: memory data size PSIZE[1:0]: peripheral data size
    *DMA_S1CR &= ~(7<<25);  // Channel 0 selected
    *DMAMUX1_C1CR |=(9<<0);
    //*DMA_S1CR |= (1 << 4);//IT TC
    //*DMA_S1CR |= (1 << 3);//IT HTC
    //NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_IRQn);
}
void DMA_Config (void){
     
  *DMA_S1NDTR = 0x00000003;   // Set the size of the transfer
  *DMA_S1PAR = 0x40022040;  // Source address is peripheral address
  *DMA_S1M0AR = 0x30000000;  // Destination Address is memory address
  // Enable the DMA Stream
  *DMA_S1CR |= (1<<0);  // EN =1
}


void SystemClock_Config(void) {

    /* Enable the floating-point unit. Any configuration of the
    floating-point unit must be done here prior to it being enabled */
    HWREG(0xE000ED88) = ((HWREG(0xE000ED88) & ~0x00F00000) | 0x00F00000);
    /*Var reg declaration*/
    uint32_t CR=*RCC_CR;
    uint32_t CFGR=*RCC_CFGR;
    uint32_t D1CFGR=*RCC_D1CFGR;
    uint32_t D2CFGR=*RCC_D2CFGR;
    uint32_t D3CFGR=*RCC_D3CFGR;
    uint32_t PLLCKSELR=*RCC_PLLCKSELR;
    uint32_t PLLCFGR=*RCC_PLLCFGR;
    uint32_t PLL1DIVR=*RCC_PLL1DIVR;
    uint32_t PLL1FRACR=*RCC_PLL1FRACR;
    uint32_t PLL2DIVR=*RCC_PLL2DIVR;
    uint32_t PLL2FRACR=*RCC_PLL2FRACR;
    uint32_t PLL3DIVR=*RCC_PLL3DIVR;
    uint32_t PLL3FRACR=*RCC_PLL3FRACR;
    uint32_t CIER=*RCC_CIER;
    /*------- Reset the RCC clock configuration to the default reset state -------*/
    /* Set HSION bit */
    CR = 0x00000001;
    *RCC_CR = CR;
    /* Reset CFGR register */
    CFGR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_CFGR = CFGR;
    /* Reset HSEON, CSSON , CSION,RC48ON, CSIKERON PLL1ON, PLL2ON and PLL3ON bits */
    CR &= (uint32_t)0xEAF6ED7F;
    *RCC_CR = CR;
    /* Reset D1CFGR register */
    D1CFGR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_D1CFGR = D1CFGR;
    /* Reset D2CFGR register */
    D2CFGR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_D2CFGR = D2CFGR;
    /* Reset D3CFGR register */
    D3CFGR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_D3CFGR = D3CFGR;
    /* Reset PLLCKSELR register */
    PLLCKSELR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_PLLCKSELR = PLLCKSELR;
    /* Reset PLLCFGR register */
    PLLCFGR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_PLLCFGR = PLLCFGR;
    /* Reset PLL1DIVR register */
    PLL1DIVR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_PLL1DIVR = PLL1DIVR;
    /* Reset PLL1FRACR register */
    PLL1FRACR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_PLL1FRACR = PLL1FRACR;
    /* Reset PLL2DIVR register */
    PLL2DIVR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_PLL2DIVR = PLL2DIVR;
    /* Reset PLL2FRACR register */
    PLL2FRACR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_PLL2FRACR = PLL2FRACR;
    /* Reset PLL3DIVR register */
    PLL3DIVR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_PLL3DIVR = PLL3DIVR;
    /* Reset PLL3FRACR register */
    PLL3FRACR = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_PLL3FRACR = PLL3FRACR;
    /* Reset HSEBYP bit */
    CR &= (uint32_t)0xFFFBFFFF;
    *RCC_CR = CR;
    /* Disable all interrupts */
    CIER = 0x00000000;
    *RCC_CIER = CIER;
    /* Change the switch matrix read issuing capability to 1 for the AXI SRAM target (Target 7) */
    HWREG(0x51008108) = 0x000000001;
}
```

What I did differently from you is mainly calibrate my ADC and add an ADSTART (my code is for single ended on only one chan of the ADC1). I sincerely think the issue comes from the fact that in ADC_Start() you check the ADDIS bit instead of working on the ADSTART bit in the ADC_CR register.
Thanks anyway you helped me get a better grasp of DMA config using register,
Just a noob :)